# NHibernate queries return multiple copies of the target objects

Tags: nhibernate

I have two classes mapped in NHibernate: `Dragon` and its subclass `FierceDragon`, with a few `FierceDragon`s stored stored in a table called `Dragons`.  When I run an HQL query like `from Dragon...` I get back two objects per row: the expected `FierceDragon` and an ordinary `Dragon` that's a copy of the `FierceDragon` (insofar as is possible; naturally it lacks the `FierceDragon`'s extra `Ferocity` and `TimeSinceLastMeal` properties).  In particular, their IDs are identical.  When I do `from FierceDragon` I get only `FierceDragon`s, with no extra copies, but that won't work for me in general.

Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Could you post your precise query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mystery is solved; I thought I was only mapping `FierceDragon`, but no, I was mapping `Dragon` too, both to the table `Dragons`.  Not sure why NH did that particular thing in this case, but clearly the fix is to, you know, not map separate classes to the same table.  Or if you do, at least give NH some way of distinguishing between the two in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you create your mapping correctly, that should not pose a problem.
There are 3 different ways of mapping a class-hierarchy to the DB using NHibernate.

Check out [this](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/10/nhibernate-mapping-inheritance.aspx) and [this](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance) article.

You can map both Dragon and FierceDragon to the same table, but, in that case, your table should have some nullable columns to be able to store the additional properties of FierceDragon.   Since you're talking about one table, I suppose you want to use the 'Table per class hierarchy' mapping strategy ?

Comment: No, I was using the 'map both classes without being aware of it' strategy.  When I issued a query for Dragon, NH observed that Dragon and its subclass FierceDragon were mapped, and issued two select statements, one for each, blissfully unaware that they shared a table.